# how to trigger a gcm to send a push notification to android device(using java server)

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am very new to java server side development, i have followed this link [[http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/][1]](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/%5d%5b1%5d)  and successfully implemented GCM with my android device, the problem is dont know how to trigger the GCM server while the content is updated in my db,i need to notify each and every update of my db to the user, am i need to watch the db using timer task something like that or is there any default solution to keep track of db ?

My Server side code :

```
regId = "my registration id";
                String userMessage = request.getParameter("message");               
                Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
                Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
                        .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, userMessage).build();                                
                result = sender.send(message, regId, 1);
```

have tried with many solution but till now not getting exact solution, Suggestion, ideas or related links are most welcome
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the specific functionality of your server and app, I can only offer a general solution.

Each process in your server that performs DB updates that have to be pushed to some Android devices via GCM can write the messages and the registration IDs to some kind of queue.

Then you can have another process (or processes) that would consume the queue of GCM messages, and send them to Google. These processes can handle failures (retry sending the messages in case of temporary failures), and update your database of registration IDs if they receive responses with canonical registration IDs or errors such as  InvalidRegistration or NotRegistered.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, how can i keep track the db for updates, am i need to use timer task to watch the updates of db???

Comment: @Bindhu The thread that sends the GCM messages can run in a loop and wake every X seconds to check if there are new messages in the queue to send.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what am expecting, am newbie to this so that not able to get clearly, now am got a idea.